# bochs on Fedora 22: Failed loading module libbx_usb_uhci.so

Tags: fedora, osdev, bochs

I ran into some trouble using BOCHS (Paket bochs-2.6.2-7.fc22.x86_64) on my brand new installed Fedora 22 AMD64 system. I used yum to get bochs but if I try to start a simulation I get an error message:

```
00000000000p[ ] >>PANIC<< dlopen failed for module 'usb_uhci': /usr/lib64/bochs/plugins/libbx_usb_uhci.so: undefined symbol: _ZTV12usb_device_c
================================================== ======================
Event type: PANIC
Device: [ ]
Message: dlopen failed for module 'usb_uhci': /usr/lib64/bochs/plugins/libbx_usb_uhci.so: undefined symbol: _ZTV12usb_device_c
```

I searched on the web for a solution with no success.

Comment: were you able to fix this ? I am getting the exact same problem !

Comment: @bhuwansahni I've posted a solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you were doing some os development here. I was; reading the [little os book](http://littleosbook.github.com/)

Anyway, from [this](https://sourceforge.net/p/bochs/mailman/message/34638801/), [this](https://sourceforge.net/p/bochs/discussion/39592/thread/58822184/) and **[this](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1180851)** it seems like this was an issue that was resolved sometime after 2013. If you install via package manager you'll get an older 2.6.x. version. As of *Jul 17 2016* `2.6.8` is the latest you can get from the source.

So for what worked was getting the [latest source from here](http://bochs.sourceforge.net/svn-snapshot/bochs-20160717.tar.gz).

Download the tar.gz from the previous link to a location. `cd` into that directory,  Ensure **you remove bochs** if you installed it via `yum`, `apt-get` or `dnf` for Fed 23+

Then do:

```
tar -xvf bochs*
#the extra build flags for if your're doing osdev
./configure --enable-debugger --enable-disasm --with-all-libs
make
sudo make install
```

Viola! Hopefully it should work for you and any poor souls out there who were lost like me.